# Can you add an if statement in the axios.put options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, axios

I'm using React with axios for my put method. I have a form that a user can update the username, password, email etc. I want to only update the server data if a user has input something otherwise don't get the input.

Can I add if statement logic in the method?

If not what would be a method to exclude empty inputs from the put?

Example:

```
axios.put(`myapi.com/users/${user}`, { 
   if (user, email, password) {
     Username: user, Email: email, Password: password 
   } else if (user, password) {
     Username: user, Password: password }...etc},
  { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}}
  )
  .then(response => {
    let userData = response.data;
    updatedUser(userData);
   ... 
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but not using `if`, you need to use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```js
axios.put(`myapi.com/users/${user}`, 
  ( user && email && password ? { 
      Username: user, Email: email, Password: password 
    } : ((user && password) ? {
        Username: user, Password: password 
      } 
      : {} // default, or add more cases
    )
    }),
  { headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }
).then(response => {
  let userData = response.data;
  updatedUser(userData);
  ... 
})
```

Comment: yeah, I don't know either. I think some people just pass quick judgement when they see JS code that doesn't parse, and conclude that the OP didn't try very hard. But in your case it was clear -- at least to me -- that it was just a means of expressing an idea.